# Turning a Javascript Object Value into a Global Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have an object from FullCalender

```
events: [

                <?

                $sql =   "Query removed";

                 if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$sql))
                {
                    // Fetch one and one row
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {

                    echo "  {
                    title: '".$row['eName']."',
                    backgroundColor: 'green',
                    start: '".$row['scheduledDate']."',
                    eventID: '".$row['eID']."'

                }, " ;

                    }
                    // Free result set
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
                ?>
            ],
            eventClick: function(event) {

                    $('#modifydialog').dialog('open');
                    $("#notes").val(event.eventID);
                    var eID = event.eventID;
            }
```

I am trying desperately to make an object (the event.eventID into a global variable so I can use it here:

```
   var eID = '';
// handles the click event for link 1, sends the query
function getOutput() {
    getRequest(
        'checkDelete.php?sID=<?echo $sID;?>&eID='+eID, // URL for the PHP file
        drawOutput,  // handle successful request
        drawError    // handle error
    );
```

Basically, I'm trying to take the value, and pop it into the ajax url for the get statement - I am open to suggestions if there are better ways. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
 'checkDelete.php?sID=<?echo $sID;?>&eID='+$("#notes").val()
```

that is if the value of this element won't be changed in the meantime. You can also declare `eID` in the global scope and use `eID = event.eventID;` to set it.

```
var eID;
events: [
          ....
        ],
        eventClick: function(event) {
                .....
                eID = event.eventID;
        }
```

you can even do this:

```
window.eID = event.eventID;
```

Comment: When I try that, it is returned as "undefined"...I will post more code-

Comment: Your answer worked I believed - I have some other issues I didn't realize I had. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertDickey I'm glad I could help. Good luck.